# Geonames get places close by

Tags: geonames

i was wondering how use the Geonames web service to return all places close to a certain lat long combination. The example of what i would like to do is [here.](http://www.geonames.org/maps/google_-29.536_31.214.html) See all the towns listed at the bottom in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On that page:

http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html

You find all web services available.

Service No.9 findNearby is a good candidate for your task.

In that "findNearby" Service you pass in:
Parameters : lat,lng, featureClass,featureCode, radius: radius in km (optional), maxRows : max 
For featureClass and Code you have to read a bit the docu.

Comment: thanks..you are right about me needing to read the doc. Going to go and sleep now.